# Installing phalcon dev tools on El Capitan

Tags: phalcon, osx-elcapitan

I have phalcon 2.0 and I used to use the phalcon dev tools with it. In my mac I had Yosemite and this weekend I updated to El Capitan to be able to work with some swift projects. The problem is that after the SO update my phalcon dev tools stopped working and I can't run this command anymore to install phalcon dev tools:

```
ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
```

I get this error message in terminal: `ln: /usr/bin/phalcon: Operation not permitted`

It has to do with that in El Capitan now you have some read only folders, even for the admin.

Have anyone figured out a way to install the phalcon dev tools in El Capitan already?

Thanks

Comment: You need to run that command as root. In El Capitan, your main user is not the _real_ root anymore. You need to specifically run that command with root privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the command that made the phalcon tools work again :

```
ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/local/bin/phalcon
```